# Renaming images of ImageCollection to add band name at end on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, multi-band, download, band

I am trying to batch download an image collection using Rodrigo E. Principe's tool but I want to download each band seperately by image.select function.

When I download a single band, I get the name of the image, but I want to add name of the band to the image id.

Example of the id I get while downloading band 'B4':
20190731T083609_20190731T084610_T36TVK

Want I want to achieve while downloading band 'B4':
20190731T083609_20190731T084610_T36TVK_B4

This is the code I use for download.

````
var tile = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon((([31.8168273934012,40.644794803776],[31.8338683044504, 39.655752572233],[33.1137799145259 ,39.6615512269476],[33.1154430676193, 40.6507988109166])))

var geom= ee.Geometry.Rectangle([31.5, 40.4, 33.1, 39.4])

// Load the Sentinel-2 ImageCollection.
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");

//ImageCollection filtered by date and region
    var filtered = ee.ImageCollection(sentinel2
   .filterDate("2019-07-27", "2019-08-03").filterBounds(geometry));


Map.addLayer(filtered, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 2000}, 'filtered')
Map.centerObject(filtered)

//Clip layer
Map.addLayer(table,{},'140bin')

//clipping Function
var clipimage = function(image) {
return image.clip(table);
};


//Function to Select band
var redband =function(image){
  return image.select('B4')
}



//Select band to download
var red = filtered.map(redband)
Map.addLayer(red,{ max: 2000}, 'red')
Map.centerObject(filtered)

//how many images
var count = filtered.size()
print("Count", count)


//Single Band Batch Download
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(filtered, '140binclip',   {scale: 10, region: geom.getInfo()})```
````

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you aim to achieve with this, but here is a simple way how you could do that.

```
//Single Band Batch Download
var bands = filtered.first().bandNames().getInfo();
for (var i = 0; i < bands.length; i++){
  print(bands[i])
  batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(filtered.select(bands[i]), '140binclip'+bands[i],   
                                         {scale: 10, region: geom.getInfo()})
}
```

Couldn't check it because you code is not reproducible. Use the 'Get Link' button to share the link and assets.